# How to do login with ajax and json for hibrid mobile app

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am a novice coder. For my project I am trying to make a login form for mobile web using `json` and `ajax`. I have tried to test the code from tutorial [*here*](http://www.gajotres.net/advanced-jquery-mobile-tutorial-part-2-client-server-communication/) by my self.

and this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JQM Demo Login</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libs/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="login">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h3>Login Page</h3>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <form id="check-user" class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all" data-ajax="false">
                <fieldset>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="username">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" name="username" id="username" class="ui-theme-b" />
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="username">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" value="" name="password" id="password" class="ui-theme-b" />
                    </div>
                    <input type="button" data-theme="b" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login">
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="second">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h3>Welcome Page</h3>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

with javascript:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#login', function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#submit', function() {
        if ($('#username').val().length > 0 && $('#password').val().length > 0) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'check.php',
                data: {action: 'login', formData: $('#check-user').serialize()},
                type: 'post',
                async: 'true',
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $.mobile.loading('show', {theme:"a", text:"Please wait...", textonly:true, textVisible:true});
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $.mobile.loading('hide');
                },
                success: function(result) {
                    if (result.status) {
                        user.name = result.message;
                        $.mobile.changePage('#second');
                    } else {
                        alert('logon unsuccessful!');
                    }
                },
                error: function(request,error) {
                    alert('Network error has accurred please try again!');
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert('Please fill all necessary fields!');
        }
        return false;
    });
});

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#second', function() {
    $.mobile.activePage.find('.ui-content').html('Welcome' + user.name);
});

var user = {name : null};
```

It's directing the data with ajax to check.php in the same server in localhost.

```
<?php
    $action = $_POST['action'];

    parse_str($_POST['formData'], $output);

    $username = $output['username'];
    $password = $output['password'];

    $output = array('status' => true, 'message' => $username);
    echo json_encode($output);  

?>
```

In the link that provided by tutorial '[example](http://example.gajotres.net/json/index.html)' the code is working fine. But for me I am getting below error when I tried to implement the same.

> *Network error has occurred please try again!*

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? and how to make it success if the username and password authenticated with `MySQL` database?

Comment: I got it fix now. But, in page second the result is "welcome undefined". I think result user.name is not contained by username. Can anyone tell me any problem detail and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Your JS code seems fine, I suggest you display the "error" for debugging Purpose. Try console.log(error) in the error method.

Anyways, the possible reasons could be:

1. The data returned by check.php is not in json. so if you are returning "YES" or "1" etc  then ensure that it is JSON format.
2. There is some exception/error in the SQL query. hence you are getting the custom message.

Comment: So, is there some ways to make the return content in json format? Btw, it's not syncing with database sql yet.